# Initiate instant. phone call with react native on expo

Tags: react-native, expo

code given as

```
    const handlePhone = async (number: any) => {
    if (!number) {
        Alert.alert("NOPE")
    } else {
        const url = `tel:${number}`
        try {
            const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);

            if (supported) {
                await Linking.openURL(url);
            } else {
                console.error("Cannot open phone dialer.");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

};
```

I keep receiving the error : Unable to open URL  when using an ios simulator

Comment: I think it is about your iPhone Simulator. You need to check with Real Device. It works in Android perfectly. Let me what is going on. I'll try to help.